# How do I select / filter out / drop columns containing only NA or N/A string in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

After reading from excel,

```
xl = read_excel(path, sheet=1)
df = data.frame(xl)
```

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
|Product|Location |Count  |Count    |Sold   |Sold     |Discount|Discount|
|-------|---------|-------|---------|-------|---------|--------|---------|
|abc    |NA       |N/A    |123      |N/A    |123      |N/A     |123      |
|def    |NA       |N/A    |456      |N/A    |453      |N/A     |543      |
|ghi    |NA       |N/A    |166      |N/A    |242      |N/A     |653      |
```

I want to remove all columns that contains only NA or "N/A".

I have tried these codes:

```
1. df2 <- df %>% select(~sum(!is.na(.)) > 0)
2. df2 <- df %>% select_if(~sum(!is.na(.)) > 0)
3. df2 <- df[!sapply(df, function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
4. na.omit(df) # This remove rows instead of columns
```

But it seems like the columns with "N/A" is still in my dataframe.
There's a lot more columns that have such "N/A" values so I cannot be specifying
exactly / hardcoding which columns that have it.

Comment: janitor has a function for that https://rdrr.io/cran/janitor/man/remove_empty.html

Comment: current dplyr practices look like this mtcars %>% select(where(~ sum(.x) > 5000))

Comment: Do the columns really have N/A instead of NA? Is N/A actually text?

Comment: your annonymous functions are using ´.´ but since you are inside the tidyverse it should instead use .x

Comment: @Bruno, I believe that is a recommendation, not a requirement. The `.` should work just fine. Has there been discussion of removing support for it?

Comment: @JohnPaul yes N/A is in text.

Comment: so if N/A is text, `is.na()` won't find it. You need `=="N/A"` as the comparison.

Comment: @JohnPaul what if a column has only a single cell/row that has "N/A"? Will it also delete this column? I am looking to delete columns that contain only "N/A" and not other values.

Comment: Just as an additional information, `read_excel()` has an argument `na`, which you could set to `"N/A"` in order to transform them into "real" NAs, which `is.na()` would detect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example

```
DF<-data.frame(X=1:5, Y=6:10, Z="N/A", W=c(1:4,"N/A"))

DF %>% select(where(~!all(.x=="N/A")))
```

This makes a data frame with one column of all "N/A" and another with just one "N/A" value and some regular data columns. The `all` part will be true if all the values are "N/A" but not otherwise. Using the `!` in front of `all` negates that, so you get the columns that don' have all `N/A`. Output is:

```
 X  Y   W
1 1  6   1
2 2  7   2
3 3  8   3
4 4  9   4
5 5 10 N/A
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on John Paul's code, this deselects columns with `"N/A"` **and** `NA`:

```
DF %>% 
   select(
          where(~!all(.x == "N/A"|is.na(.x)))
         )
```

Test data:

```
DF<-data.frame(A = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), X=1:5, Y=6:10, Z="N/A", W=c(1:4,"N/A"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great solution! worked for me as well :D

Answer (score 1):

Base R version:

```r
df[,sapply(df, function(z) any(!is.na(z) & !z %in% "N/A"))]
#   Product Count Sold Discount
# 1     abc   123  123      123
# 2     def   456  453      543
# 3     ghi   166  242      653
```

Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(Product = c("abc", "def", "ghi"), Location = c(NA, NA, NA), Count = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), Count = c(123L, 456L, 166L), Sold = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), Sold = c(123L, 453L, 242L), Discount = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), Discount = c(123L, 543L, 653L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(\(x) any(x != "N/A" & !is.na(x)), df1)
```